# BASH: If statement needed to run if number of files in directory is 2 or greater

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, count, directory

I have the following BASH script:
http://pastebin.com/CX4RN1QW

There are two sections within the script that I want to run only if the number of files in the directory are 2 or greater. They are marked by `## Begin file test here` and `## End file test.`

I am very sensitive about the script, I don't want anything else to change, even if it simplifies it.

I have tried:

```bsh
if [ "$(ls -b | wc -l)" -gt 1 ];
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: There are always at least two file(name)s in every directory: `.` and `..`.  OK, so these are hard links to other names, but have you considered what you want to do about links?  Also consider if you want filenames starting `.` (like `.profile`) that would be ignored by many of the solutions that follow.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the external `ls` command, you can use a glob to check for the existence of files in a directory:

EDIT I missed that you were looking for > 2 files. Updated.

```
shopt -s nullglob # cause unmatched globs to return empty, rather than the glob itself
files=(*) # put all file in the current directory into an array
if (( "${#files[@]}" >= 2 )); then # since we only care about existence, we only need to expand the first element
   ...
fi
shopt -u nullglob # disable null glob (not required)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, at least not in the context of my script.

Comment: @user1486782 - There are no find commands in your question or my answer. The issue with your find command is somewhere else.

Comment: `l-print0` is not a valid option for find.

Comment: Correct, I found the issue with the find command, my mistake. But I fixed that, and the code you posted does not work. The statements will always execute, whether there are more than 1 file(s) in the folder or not.

Comment: it checks for any file, not at least 2 files. It would have to use "${#files[@]}", but that's unsafe if you have wierd filenames.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx - can you show an example where expanding the number of elements in an array is "unsafe"?

Comment: @user1486782 - I updated the answer to check for 2 ore more files, rather than just a single file

Comment: Not really, but does it handle whitespace well?

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx: Yes, globbing in an array is safe with whitespace.

Comment: @user1486782: It looks perfect to me, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @lynkxlynxlynx: What happens is that it enters a directory with only 1 file in it. It then removes the footer, despite it depending on the if statement that says it shouldn't process if the files are 1 or less. I put my edited script here: http://pastebin.com/Q2QcJVQK

Comment: make sure you're globbing in the correct dir, the logic looks fine.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx Apparently my logic is NOT fine. In my script I needed to use files=($dir/*) instead of files=(*). I came to the conclusion that although the script is processing all files underneath subdirectories, it's not CD'ing IN to the directories, it's processing AGAINST the directories. Adding files=($dir/*) to it seems to have told it what I wanted to do. I am testing now, and hate to speak to soon, but it appears that it may be working.

Comment: hehe, I was talking about @jordanm's logic. This will also be the reason the `ls` solution didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You would need `ls -1` there for it to work, since -b doesn't make it print one item per line. Alternatively use `find`, since it does that by default.

Comment: As a further note, that is ls dash one not ls dash l

Comment: Unfortunately, with that it won't do any of the statements even if there are more than 1 file in the directory.

Comment: you did use -1, right? I rolled back the other users bad edit.

Comment: Piping `ls` causes it to act as if `-1` had been used so it's not necessary to supply that option.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx Yes, I did use -1.